# How to ask politely for the caller's name on a phone call

Tags: phrases, telephone

In case I've received a call and I don't know the caller I want to politely ask the name of the caller. What should I say in this situation?

Comment: 'May I ask who I am speaking with' usually does the trick.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Can you narrow down your question at all? There are probably hundreds of ways to ask, from *Sorry, who's this?* to *And with whom may I say I have the pleasure of speaking?* A simple web search on "telephone etiquette" should turn up an ample number of acceptable options. As initially presented, I think this question is either too broad, too opinion-based, or too-lacking in preliminary research to be answerable here.

Comment: @choster Thanks my friend. I am waiting for a call from a company which may want to hire me and at the first call I want to ask for the callers name very politely.

Comment: May I ask who's calling?

Comment: ewormuth's is the best, in my opinion; you may add a "please" at the end, since this is (hopefully) a potential employer calling!

Comment: @MohammadChamanpara Well..and exactly what did I teach you?

Comment: @ShaonaBose I realized that using "Thanks in advance for your help" at the end of my request is wrong. Thank you again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To whom am I speaking?**

**With whom do I have the pleasure of speaking?**

**Who's calling, please?**

If the call is for someone else:

**Who may I say is calling?**

Comment: Also, "I'm sorry, what was your name again?" With this phrase, you're pretending the other person was polite enough to say it (even if they didn't) and you just didn't hear.

Comment: Zwi, why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Yeshe - I didn't want to make an orphan answer that was one line, or steal all of Steven's good answers to throw in with mine!  But combined, they make a nice, rounded list of possibilities.

Comment: A shortened version of one of Steven's proposals is "With whom do I have the pleasure?"  But in my experience, both versions of this one whiz right past most people.

Answer (score -1):

You should say

> I would appreciate if you can tell me your name again.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual [answers](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). If you have a [question](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.